# What's the role of the Model in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, model

I've read a few articles about MVC but there's one thing that isn't clear to me. What is the role of the model in practical term.

Does the model represent the business object?
Or is it just a class that help send information from the controller to the view?

Take for example two business class (data populated from the database)

```
Class Image
    Property FileName As String
    Property CreatedBy As User
End Class

Class User
    Property UserName as String
End Class
```

Will "Image" be the model or should I create a new class?

In the model, should I create a UserName property that will fetch it's data from the User object?

```
Class ImageModel
    Property FileName As String
    Property CreatedBy As User

    ReadOnly Property UserName As String
        Get
            Return User.UserName
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are many views on this, but in my experience, there are 2 major views of the `Model`:

### ViewModel

This is a POCO that simply contains all the data necessary to display the `View`.  The data is usually populated by the `Controller`.

### Fat Model, Skinny Controller

The `Model` does the majority of the business-work.  It contains and populates all the data that is needed by the `View`, and is used by the `Controller` to save data, etc.

#### The beauty of MVC

The beauty of MVC is that it's OPEN!  You can choose any type of model you want ... you can put all your data into `ViewState`, into a `Model`, into a `ViewModel` that contains a bunch of `Model`s, whatever.  It's really up to you.  The Model, View, and Controller are blank canvases that can be used however you like.

#### What I use

My team has done a lot of MVC work, and we have tried many of these different methods.  We finally decided that our favorite was the **Fat Model, Skinny Controller** paradigm.
I believe that this pattern is the best at "keeping it simple" and "don't repeat yourself", and it definitely maintains the "separation of concerns".
Here's how our code is organized:

- Controllers

  - Handles everything that pertains to HTTP requests - redirects, authentication, web safety, encoding, etc.
  - Gives all "input" to a `Model`, and gives the `Model` to the view.  Does NOT access Business or Data layers.
- Views

  - Handles all HTML and JSON generation
  - Only accesses data from the strongly-typed `Model`
- Models

  - Responsible for making all updates, calling Business and Data layers, loading all data
  - Handles all validation and errors, and returns these to the Controller
  - Contains properties of all data that is required for the `View`, and populates itself

Even though this sounds like a generic principle of MVC, it quickly becomes obvious that MVC does not require these principles, which is why many projects use other principles.

#### Example

Here's an example `Model`.  The Controller creates it, it populates itself, and the Controller passes it to the View.

```
public class UsersModel
{
    protected UserBusiness userBusiness = new UserBusiness();
    
    public UsersModel(string editUserName)
    {
        // Load all users:
        this.Users = userBusiness.GetAllUsers();
        
        // Load the user to be edited:
        this.EditUser = (editUserName == null) ? null : userBusiness.GetUser(editUserName);
    }
    
    public List<User> Users { get; private set;}
    public User EditUser { get; private set; }
}
```

All the "user business logic" in this case is in a different project (our "Business Layer"), because we have a large system.  But smaller projects don't require this ... the Model can contain business logic, and even data-access code.

Comment: Thanks! You got me to understand that there are different type of model (ViewModel, BusinessModel, ...)

Answer (score 1):

There are many models. It both can be business data (or domain) objects (Controller -> Datasource, and vice-versa), business rules (act on domain objects) or view models (Controller to View, and vice-versa).

You don't explicitly have to define the username again in `ImageModel`.