# What is the use of the model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am a beginner at MVC, and I am not quite sure in what way I should use or when to make a model?

I couldn't find anything spesific about just the model part of MVC online, so I was hoping someone here could clarify a little about it.

Comment: duplicate at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8406822/whats-the-role-of-the-model-in-mvc

Comment: Yes, the duplicate uses some VB but the answers are good.

Answer (score 0):

Model Is used to Defined Properties of our Application By which we can access our Data..its Work like a Data Link Layer
its Play a Mediatary Role between Contoller & View.

Please Go through With the below mentioned link..
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/adding-a-model

Answer (score -1):

It's a part where the application connected with the database, imagine the application is your home, the View is your design of your house, then the Controller is your front door. And the Model is inside of your house where no one can see it, except you permitted 'em.

Hope this helps you.